# Possible DNA combinations from parent to child.

Tags: combinatorics

I'm told each person has 4 DNA markers and each parent passes on 2 each to each child. How many possible combinations can be past to their children.

Answer (score 1):

***Hint:***

Think about it like this: You must combine one pair of markers in the father with one pair in the mother. How many ways is there to choose a pair in each parent? Call this number $N$. For each pair chosen in the father, you can choose $N$ different pairs from the mother. How many possible combinations does this give?